# Not able to access the column of a data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

There is a column in excel with the name **12/31/2018** means **31-Dec-18**.
When i am reading the excel file into pandas then this column name is mapped as **2018-12-31 00:00:00**, which i am not able to access alone with loc.

This column contains the int type values, but the column name is date type.

Please help me to access this column with loc.

Comment: Show us which code you have tried so far...

Comment: df.loc[:,"2018-12-31 00:00:00"]

Comment: what does your df.columns return? you might get how your column is named

Comment: df.columns returns this column as 2018-12-31 00:00:00, but when i using this same name with loc then it is giving a key error. I am not understanding where is the problem is actually..

Answer (score 0):

is it necessary to acces it via loc? df[“2018-12-31 00:00:00"] should let you get the values

Comment: I have already tried this method also, i totally don't know why it is giving the key error in this case also, Thanks for your help Carlos..